# toggleClass for interchanging ul li's

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I am probably missing something really obvious.

I am trying to make a toggleClass to switch out a ul's li's from english to spanish.

essentially just want the spanish ul to display when I click on the spanish text / button and the english ul to display when I click on the english text/button.

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/TonyTheOnly/k92ayp24/

any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
        $(".burger-nav").on("click", function(){
            
            $("nav ul").toggleClass("open");
        });
});


$(document).ready(function () {

    
    $(".spanish").on("click", function () {
        
        $("englishNav").toggleClass("spanishNav");
    });

       $(".english").on("click", function () {
        
        $("spanishNav").toggleClass("englishNav");
    });
    
  });
```

```css
.spanishNav {
  display:none;
}

.spanish{
  cursor:pointer;
}

.english{
  cursor:pointer;
}
nav {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10%
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    
    position: relative;
    
}

nav a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
}


     
    .burger-nav{
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    float: right;
    background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png");
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
   .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
     nav ul {
        overflow: hidden;
        background: white;
        height:0;
        
    }

    nav ul.open {
        height: auto;
        margin-top:150px;
        margin-right: 100px;
    }
     nav ul li{
        float:none;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        
    }
    nav ul li a {
        color: black;
        padding: 10px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <nav>
       <a class="burger-nav"></a>
        <ul class="englishNav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
         <ul class="spanishNav">
            <li><a href="#">Homeo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Abouto</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Serviceso</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p class="spanish">
        spanish
        </p>
        <p class="english">
        english
        </p>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is current output & what is expected output ?

Comment: I see...even clicking on spanish..is not changing the language ..is that the issue??

Comment: I would use a hidden variable to store the last clicked lanugage....

Comment: You'll need to fix your jQuery selectors to include the dot before the class name. From $("englishNav") to $(".englishNav") and the same for the Spanish one too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using `toggleClass` incorrectly. `toggleClass` is for adding/removing a class. To achieve the effect you want we merely need to hide/show either the `.spanishNav` or `.englishNav` elements depending on which language is selected.

One solution is to show/hide the Spanish/English nav elements depending on which button is selected. Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".burger-nav").on("click", function() {
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("open");
  });

  $(".spanish").on("click", function() {
    $(".englishNav").hide();
    $(".spanishNav").show();
  });

  $(".english").on("click", function() {
    $(".englishNav").show();
    $(".spanishNav").hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.spanishNav {
  display: none;
}

.spanish {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.english {
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10%
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.burger-nav {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: right;
  background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png");
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  height: 0;
}

nav ul.open {
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

nav ul li {
  float: none;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #404040;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <a class="burger-nav"></a>
    <ul class="englishNav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="spanishNav">
      <li><a href="#">Homeo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Abouto</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Serviceso</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="spanish">
      spanish
    </p>
    <p class="english">
      english
    </p>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget **dot**
just change `englishNav` to `.englishNav` and `spanish` to `.spanish`